# Spring JPA difficult delete

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can someone help with the following model, implemented, but unable to delete as desired

1. Author OneToMany with Book
2. Book ManyToMany with Genre
3. Genre ManyToMany with Book
   I can create the db and add records.  I believe my cascade designation is wrong as I cannot do the following
4. From Author, delete a book(yes odd,copyright issues:) have it deleted from Books BUT also have it removed from Genre
   The problem is depending on what cascade I either get FK violation on Genre delete or FK violation on Book delete.  Is it a deadlock?  It is a trivial pattern and must be solveable.  Thank you

Comment: Start without the cascade and perhaps never add it back. Use a service layer and do what you need to do carefully. Further, should author and book be manytomany?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I think that cascade is best used to handle the case when all child relations are deleted but still I think it's a complicated annotation and not well understood by most. I think that if the `Book` entity owns the authors and genres relationships then the ORM has no choice but to delete the relations when a book is deleted.

When I setup a simple springboot project it seems to take case of all this.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    @lombok.ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Book> books;
}

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Genre {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres")
    @lombok.ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Book> books;
}

@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Author> authors;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Genre> genres;
}
```

And an simple example:

```
Author author = authorRepository.save(Author.builder().build());
Genre genre = genreRepository.save(Genre.builder().build());
Book book = bookRepository.save(Book.builder().authors(Collections.singleton(author)).genres(Collections.singleton(genre)).build());
System.out.println(book);
bookRepository.delete(bookRepository.getOne(book.getId()));
```

And the logs seem to indicate that authors and genres are cleaned up when a book is deleted.

```
Hibernate: insert into author (id) values (null)
Hibernate: insert into genre (id) values (null)
Hibernate: insert into book (id) values (null)
Hibernate: insert into book_authors (books_id, authors_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into book_genres (books_id, genres_id) values (?, ?)
Book(id=1, authors=[Author(id=1)], genres=[Genre(id=1)])
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_1_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?
Hibernate: delete from book_authors where books_id=?
Hibernate: delete from book_genres where books_id=?
Hibernate: delete from book where id=?
```

I think this is doing what your questioned is about.

Comment: Wow.  What a professional and succinct answer, ty.  There are several teachable techniques in there.  Your lombok.ToString.Exclude I discovered less elgantly needed a JsonBackReference.

Comment: Yea, also the `lombok.EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` should sorted as well. See [Lombok & Hibernate: How to Avoid Common Pitfalls](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/)